# Magento dynamic text in layout xml file using addText

Tags: magento

I currently have this:

```
    <block type="core/text" name="top.address" as="topAddress">
        <action method="addText"><text>PO BOX 1124, Rockdale, Sydney, NSW 2216, Australia</text></action>
    </block>
```

But, when I need to update address, I have to do it manually here in the layout file. I want to pull address from store config ( **general/store_information/address** ) so, I can update everywhere on the site from one location easily.

I guess it can be done directly on the template like this:

```
<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address') ?>
```

But I want to try with layout, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer - no. There is no functionality for it. That's not to say that it couldn't be done. There is an attribute that you can use on an action tag - `ifconfig`. It looks to see if a system config flag is set, and if it returns true, then it will proceed with the action. You could *override* or *extend* `Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php` to add that functionality.

There are a number of options to this problem, though.

1. You can use templates, like you mentioned.
2. If you are wanting to avoid a template, you can create a block that extends `Mage_Core_Block_Text` and specify the `_toHtml` method, with the code that you provided.
3. **The best:** I would see creating a generic block in a generic module that is used to pull system config requests and output them as text. You could either have it be a custom action/method, or send along an attribute value, which will end up in the data array for the block, which you could then lookup in `_toHtml`.

Comment: Plus it can be easily done with Static blocks, so it'd be possible to edit this address from Admin panel http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-create-and-edit-static-blocks and than call it from either template or layout

Comment: Thanks @JMax, Just wanted to see if that's possible as I couldn't find anyone doing that way. I decided to go with #1 as I had same thing in mind as 2nd choice too.

Comment: @SergeiGuk I really don't want to use static block, as address is already available from store config but thanks for your input too.

Answer (score 4):

My answer might be to oudated, but I faced with such problem just now I found an alternative way to solve it:

1. In layout you can specify `core/text` block and set its text via helper. You can use any suitable reference.

   ```
   <reference name="before_body_end">
       <block type="core/text" name="some.config">
           <action method="addText">
               <text helper="module_name/data/getSomeConfig" />
           </action>
       </block>
   </reference>
   ```
2. Declare `getSomeConfig` function in the helper:

   ```
   public function getSomeConfig()
   {
       return Mage::getStoreConfig('your_config_path');
   }
   ```

In a such way you can even pass some dynamic data into javascript code.